# Starting airflow with Docker - trigger ERROR

Tags: docker, triggers, airflow

I am new to Docker so I have followed the official guide here for running Airflow with it-https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html

When I start Airflow all services with  'docker-compose up' in Ubuntu, I get  "ERROR - Triggerer's async thread was blocked for ... seconds, likely by a badly-written trigger. Set PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1 to get more information on overrunning coroutines."

Any idea how to fix this issue is appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

This can be fixed by allocating more resources as mentioned [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#before-you-begin), by default docker allocates 2gb of memory and 4gb is needed.

You can follow this [link](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/) for mac and [link](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/) for Windows on how to change your resource allocation.

Also check your `docker-compose` version, you can do so by running `docker-compose --version`.

Comment: I have the same problem but increasing Docker memory didn't do the trick (I went up to 7Go). Just FYI, I'm running : 

- Mac0S Monterey 12.2.1
- docker-compose : 1.29.2

Comment: Adjusting memory did not help

Answer (score 0):

It's not direct related with my case. I had this issue in the Kubernetes.
I found many these error in the sentry. i also increase trigger's memory request 1536MiB and it had better much. (only daily 10 error) I think it depends on your usage. but if you have this issue on k8S, it's valuable to test.