# Docker/Airflow trigger and memory issue

Tags: docker, triggers, airflow

I've just started using docker/airflow, and have run into the following error:

"airflow-triggerer_1  | [2022-08-26 17:25:52,620] {triggerer_job.py:347} ERROR - Triggerer's async thread was blocked for 8.37 seconds, likely by a badly-written trigger. Set PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1 to get more information on overrunning coroutines."

The answer to the error is supplied in the following link, which is that not enough memory has been allocated in docker - I need to provide 5 GB, and have only provided 4:
[Starting airflow with Docker - trigger ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70489760/starting-airflow-with-docker-trigger-error)

However, when I go into the settings in docker, I cannot move the memory resource past 4 GB :

what I see on my docker resource screen

[image: 1]

I'm wondering why it is that I cannot move the tab past 4 GB, and if there's anyway to work around it.

Cheers